# iptables: redirect port to server that's bound to a specific IP

Tags: linux, iptables, ip, virtualhost

On a Linux box with multiple IPs, I'm having a problem redirecting a privileged port to an unprivileged port on which a server is listening that's bound to a specific IP.

Add this rule to iptables to redirect incoming traffic from port 80 to 8080:

```
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --protocol tcp --dport 80 \
    --jump REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Then start a netcat to listen on all IPs, port 8080:

```
nc -l 0.0.0.0 8080
```

Then send a packet to port 80 from another machine:

```
echo foo | nc 10.0.0.39:80
echo foo | nc 10.0.0.39:8080
```

Both these packets are received. Now for the strange thing. When you make netcat listen on a specific IP, it doesn't see the redirected packet.

```
nc -l 10.0.0.39 8080
```

Now the packet sent to port 80 is not received; only the packet on port 8080. The difference is obviously how the server binds the listening port -- 0.0.0.0 works but a specific IP doesn't.

The problem is not in netcat, because nginx (where I do IP-based vhosting) has the same problem.

I tried to extend the iptables rule by specifying that the destination address is 10.0.0.39, but this still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirecting, or transparently masquerading the thing away from your client applications? If you want transparency, something like this might work

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.39:8080
iptables -A OUTPUT -t nat -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.39:8080
```

Comment: That works as expected. To make IP-based vhosting work, you have to also filter by --dst:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.0.39 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.39:8080`

Now you can start two servers listening on different IPs but the same ports, and send a packet to one or the other.

I was just using the iptables terminology, they call it "redirecting" there.